# Java NIO Selector select() returns 0 although channels are ready

Tags: java, nio

My Java NIO Selector is implemented using [select()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select%28%29) so it blocks until any of these occur:

1. a registered channel is ready
2. it is [wakeup()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#wakeup%28%29)'ed
3. the thread is interrupted

From this, I made a few assumptions about the case where `select()` returns 0:

- it must've been reason 2. or 3.
- [selectedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectedKeys%28%29) should return an empty `ResultSet`
- I don't need to call `selectedKeys()` and can continue to the next loop iteration where `select()` will be called again

However, I encountered situations where `select()` returned 0 although there is a ready channel. `selectedKeys()` returns a `Set` with 1 `SelectionKey` as expected.

Even several calls to `select()` would always return 0 until the channel was processed and the `SelectionKey` was removed. This situation basically ends up in an endless loop as `select()` does not block but always instantly return 0.

Simplified code:

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();

SocketChannel channel;

for (...) { // for each node
  // Create and connect channels...
  ...

  channel.configureBlocking(false);
  channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, someRelatedObject);
}

int ready;
Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys;
while (true) {
  ready = selector.select();
  readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();

  System.out.println("Ready channels: " + ready);
  System.out.println("Selected channels: " + readyKeys.size());

  if (ready == 0) {
    continue;
  }

  for (SelectionKey key : readyKeys) {
    if (key.isValid() && key.isReadable()) {
      // Take action...
    }

    readyKeys.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Why does `select()` return 0 although there is a ready channel?
What is the suggested way of dealing with this?

**EDIT:**

Changing this:

```
  for (SelectionKey key : readyKeys) {
    if (key.isValid() && key.isReadable()) {
      // Take action...
    }

    readyKeys.remove(key);
  }
```

to this

```
  for (SelectionKey key : readyKeys) {
    readyKeys.remove(key);

    if (key.isValid() && key.isReadable()) {
      // Take action...
    }
  }
```

solved the problem. In some cases, the code would `continue` the `for` loop before `remove()`ing the key.

**EDIT 2:**

I just recently learned that my *foreach* loop over the selected keys set is bad. *foreach* uses the set's iterator. Modifying a collection directly (not via the iterator's methods) while iterating over it may result in "arbitrary, undeterministic" behavior.

The selected keys set may provide a *fail-fast* iterator. *Fail-fast* iterators detect such modifications and throw a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) upon the next iteration. So modifying the set in a *foreach* either risks undeterministic behavior or may cause exceptions - depending on the iterator implementation.

Solution: **don't use *foreach***. Use the iterator and remove the key via [iterator.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).

```
Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator;
SelectionKey key;
while (true) {
  // ...

  iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    key = iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`select()` returns the number of keys that have *changed.* So if a key was already ready before the `select()` call then it could return 0 but `selectedKeys` could be non-empty.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, it is because you didn't remove the selected key from the selected Set.

As we usually want to remove *all* selected keys after processing the Set, you can just call `clear()` on that Set after your loop, which can be a foreach or any type of loop you want:

```
Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
for (SelectionKey k : readyKeys) {
    // Process k
}
readyKeys.clear();
```

That way, you can use any type of loop you want ("regular" `for` or iterators) and be sure all ready-keys are removed, no matter what you do inside the `for` (including the problematic `continue`). Depending on what the `iterator.remove()` does internally, it might be more efficient to call `clear()` once instead of several `iterator.remove()` (though that would probably be micro-optimization).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: "Why does `select()` return 0 although there is a ready channel?"

Comment: @EJP you're right, I have corrected it. Will that be enough to remove your downvote?

Comment: What's the advantage over instantly removing every single `SelectionKey` via `iterator.remove()`?

Comment: @riha: choosing the kind of loop you find more appropriate and make sure you don't forget any key. Unless in cases you want to have fine control on *when* / *if* you want a key to be removed.
I edited my answer to include that.